# Pair strings with numbers with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example, if I want to pair every letter in the english alphabet with a number for its position as a dictionary, how would I do that without having to create a new dictionary every time like this:

```
alphabet = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? You only needed to write this once.

Comment: I have had to make long dictionaries in the past too and i'm getting tired of always doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here are a few different ways of doing it (by no means exhaustive):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
from itertools import count

mapping = dict(zip(alphabet, count(start=1)))
print(mapping)
```

---

OR:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

mapping = {key: value for value, key in enumerate(alphabet, start=1)}
print(mapping)
```

---

OR:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

mapping = {char: ord(char)-ord('a')+1 for char in alphabet}
print(mapping)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26}
>>>
```